# How to format an assembly code?

Tags: c, text, formatting, ide, inline-assembly

I have a rather long code written in assembly language and I want to use it inside a C program using `asm()` function, but every line in the code must be quoted and a new line character ('\n') must be inserted at the end of each line in order to make it usable. Is there any text editing tool that can do that or I have to do it manually?

Comment: Why not add this functionality into a build script?

Comment: Sorry but I never used build scripts before but I am researching on that subject atm.

Comment: take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054362/mixing-c-and-assembly-files

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: @jwdonahue: In what way would an MCVE help you understand the question? Formatting the assembly source code inside a GCC `asm` construct is not in any way dependent on the algorithm or other contents of the code. It is purely a syntactic operation.

Comment: I'd recommend keeping the asm as a separate `.S` file, and assembling + linking separately.  That's cleaner and easier to edit in the future, and is how most C projects with some asm functions do things (e.g. glibc).

Comment: Is this something you intend to do once and then maintain it in the future inside the C program? Or are you wanting to maintain the assembly function in its own file? I agree with @PeterCordes that the cleanest solution is to just keep it separate and link to it from your C program. It's not hard to setup your assembly program to handle the C calling conventions and to export the function name(s) you want to call.

Comment: I guess you could do it in `perl` or `sed`, but also consider exporting the name of the function as a global and calling it from C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a program that gets the assembly code from file `a.s` and saves the formatted text into file `b.s`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
    {
    FILE *pFileA=fopen("a.s","r"),
         *pFileB=fopen("b.s","w");
    if(pFileA==NULL || pFileB==NULL)
        {
        printf("ERROR!\n");
        system("pause");
        return 1;
        }
    char a;
START:
    a=getc(pFileA);
    while(a==' ' || a=='\t' || a=='\n')
        {
        putc(a,pFileB);
        a=getc(pFileA);
        }
    if(a==EOF)
        goto END;
    putc('"',pFileB);
MID:
    while(a!='\n' && a!='"')
        {
        putc(a,pFileB);
        a=getc(pFileA);
        }
    if(a=='"')
        {
        putc(92,pFileB);
        putc(a,pFileB);
        a=getc(pFileA);
        goto MID;
        }
    putc(92,pFileB);
    putc('n',pFileB);
    putc('"',pFileB);
    putc(a,pFileB);
    goto START;
END:
    fclose(pFileA);
    fclose(pFileB);
    printf("SUCCESS!\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This would have been *much* easier in a text-processing language like `perl`.  Even more strictly line-oriented ones like `sed` or awk would be pretty easy, just append `\n"` and then append the line to an accumulator.  Also, this is not a good use of GOTO.  Use a `while(1){ ... if() break; }` loop.  Also, on error, you should use `perror` to print an error message depending on `errno`.